# Negation, Converse, or contrapositive?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

S: Every employee who is honest and persistent is successful or bored.

Would this statement be the negations, converse, or contrapositive of S?

-> All employees who are dishonest or not persistent must be unsuccessful and not bored.

Comment: What's your opinion and reasoning?

Answer (score 1):

The altered statement is the converse of the contrapositive of $S$.

Contraposive of $S$: "All employees who are unsuccessful and not bored are dishonest or not persistent."

Converse of the contrapositive of $S$: "All employees who are dishonest or not persistent are unsuccessful and not bored."

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if my notation is unfamiliar.

Write
\begin{align*}
Hx &= \text{$x$ is honest}\\
Px &= \text{$x$ is persistent}\\
Sx &= \text{$x$ is successful}\\
Bx &= \text{$x$ is bored}
\end{align*}

Then $S$ can be written $\forall x (Hx \land Px) \to (Sx \lor Bx)$.

The next statement can be written $\forall x (\neg Hx \lor \neg Px) \to (\neg Sx \land \neg Bx)$.

Can you apply De Morgan's laws to make sense of that?

Comment: so it can't be the contrapositive...or negation since for all stays the same, does it make sense if its the converse? I'm still confused.

Comment: After De Morgan, it actually appears to be the inverse, but yes that's equivalent to the converse (it's the contrapositive of the converse).